# Boolean (difference) not working properly on rather simple geometry

Tags: modifiers

This topic seems to be asked a lot.

I am very new to blender, so I am still learning the in's and out's. I am trying to use the small cube to cut out a section of the latch, however, each attempt instead removes the latch and leaves the cube. I have tried the three recommended solutions of eliminating duplicate vertices, recalculating the normals, and making sure the geometry is all closed up. Still, even with those checks, when I try to use the boolean difference modifier, it doesn't work properly.

[dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkhda29nrolh4u2/Round_top_chest.blend?dl=0)

[image: Picture of part in question]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUXUv.png

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Make Sure all the Scale values of the Smaller Simple Block are Positive ... greater than zero.

The scale values should all be positive.  Remove the negative sign.

The smaller item in the picture needs to have all scales positive for clarity and to have the boolean modifier work.

Here are suggested settings for the modifier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Were you able to get the modifier to function properly because following your suggestion didn't work for me. I tried both manually removing the negative sign and then using CRTL + A to set the scale (and even rotation). Neither worked, I simply got the same result. I also checked the larger piece's scale.

I was messing around a bit more with it and the problem seems to be originating with the larger piece. I added a new (third object) cube and was able to remove material from the little block but got the same odd problem when trying to remove from the big piece.